# Interthread communication - Manual Reset Event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to establish a pause and play communication between threads.I am spawning two threads for two forms at the startup, one is the mainthread which is for mainwindow and second thread of form2,

```
 var thread = new Thread(ThreadStart);
        thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();


    private static void ThreadStart()
        {
            Application.Run(new SecondForm()); // other form started on its own UI thread
        }
```

Mainwindow has a button on clicking which multiple threads would be spawn for different operations - it executes without pause until the intended jobs are complete.

In the second form I have two buttons stop, and start clicking on which I should be able to stop and start the mainwindow(All the child threads).

For this I am declaring 
public static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

in program.cs where two UI threads are started
and trying to invoke it from the second form on start and stop

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            Program.mre.WaitOne(); 
        });
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            Program.mre.Set();
        });
    }
```

Once I click the button on mainwindow which continues with series of operations I try to click on STOP button in secondform, this disables the second form, and the operation from the mainwindow continues, please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Come on, why would you want to use more than a single UI thread? You're most likely trying to hard to solve a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that this is a completely silly threading design, there's two issues:

- You `Invoke` on the second form, so you're blocking its messaging loop. Instead, you would want to do `mainWindow.Invoke( ... )`.
- Even that will not help you when main window spawns worker threads. It will only stop the form's message loop, not the threads it has already spawned.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Luaan....But I think this is a very thoughtful requirement, if this is implemented it would be an optimal solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. When I click on Pause button I am setting a bool say continue to false, and using this variable in a loop where actual calls to function is done.

In the same class where I have my loop I have the manual reset event initialized, when continue is false I am calling mre.WaitOne(), which would pause the current thread from execution without causing any harm to other threads.

When Play is clicked I am Setting the Manual Reset event object which would restart the thread.